# How to build preprocessor solution with Tatsu?

Tags: c-preprocessor, tatsu

I'm writing a transpiler for Tiny C code to Python code, but I need to build a preprocessor solution to replace `#define` and manage compilator C directive (#ifdef, #else, #define...)

I choose to use a pcpp module in Python but with no success... is a solution possible in a full Tatsu solution?

Comment: Perhaps you would do better asking a specific question about the problem you had using pcpp, which is an actual C preprocessor. Parser generators aren't going to help you implement a macro preprocessor.

Comment: You right, but the original code is not a C code but a script code with only preprocessor code like "#define ..." the syntaxe is not C.

Comment: in any event, macro preprocessors are not in the expected use case of a context-free grammar.

Comment: Macro preprocessors are just another form of compilers, so all of compiler theory applies to them. @rici.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of TatSu supporting pre-processing are, unfortunately, undocumented.

You can take a look at how `Buffer.include()` [is implemented](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu/blob/master/tatsu/buffering.py#L127), replacing the original lines and line information by those of the block produced by the transformation.

```py
def include(self, lines, index, i, j, name, block, **kwargs):
        blines, bindex = self._preprocess_block(name, block, **kwargs)
        assert len(blines) == len(bindex)
        lines[i:j] = blines
        index[i:j] = bindex
        assert len(lines) == len(index)
        return j + len(blines) - 1
```

Basically, you can hook into the preprocessing methods with your own `Buffer` class, and transform the text in whichever way. A proper list of `LineIndexInfo` will let the parser report errors agains original source lines.

For a preprocessor with macros, you'll probably need a parser for the preprocessor, and a parser for the main language. The trick will be making the first parser preserve the line information for the second one.

The preprocessor may run separately, but it must inject metadata enough to allow the main parser to recover the original line information.